# When building heap, is heap unique?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap

I'm studying heap & heap sorting.
There is a array : `arr[8] = {6,9,3,1,8,7,2,11}` 
When I'm trying to build the heap, using code and pencil, I faced two kinds of heap.

When using code, 
MaxHeap : 11 9 7 6 8 3 2 1

When using insertion theory, MaxHeap : 11 9 7 8 6 3 2 1

The code that i'm using :

```
int[] DoHeapSort(int[] value) {
    int length = value.length;

    for (int i = length / 2; i > 0; i--) {
        maxHeapify(value, i, length);
    }

    //print Heap
    for(int i = 0 ; i<value.length; i++)
        System.out.println(value[i]);

    return (value);
}


void maxHeapify(int[] array, int index, int heapSize) {
    int left = index * 2;
    int right = left + 1;
    int max = index;

    if (left <= heapSize && array[left - 1] > array[index - 1]) {
        max = left;
    }

    if (right <= heapSize && array[right - 1] > array[max - 1]) {
        max = right;
    }

    if (max != index) {
        swap(array, index - 1, max - 1);
        maxHeapify(array, max, heapSize);
    }
}
```

Theory, in this case, create another array for heap and insert from 6 to 11 in order. (On the other hand, code is in-place heap)

Both maxHeap results satisfied heap definition. Then Heap is not unique ?  Thanks

Answer (score 11):

That's correct. The heap constraint (which is that children are not greater than their parents) does not completely specify the heap, so there is usually more than one possible arrangement.

Comment: @user3595632: I'd go with the O(n) in-place algorithm. That's the usual implementaiton.

Comment: @user3595632: from the Wikipedia on Binary Heap: "*However, in 1974, Thomas Porter and Istvan Simon proved that the function for the average number of levels an inserted node moves up is upper bounded by the constant 1.6067. ... Thus, on average, binary heap insertion has a constant, O(1), time complexity.*" Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Insert

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: That's interesting, but doesn't address the worst case. However, if you read down just a little bit in that wikipedia article, you will encounter a much simpler proof that *building* a heap is worst-case O(n) if you do the build correctly (as opposed to inserting each element iteratively, which is worst case O(n log n) )

Comment: @user3595632: Precisely because the heap is not completely determined, it is possible to build it in worst-case O(n). Extracting the sorted sequence from the heap is O(n log n).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: That's certainly an interesting fact!  But I'm guessing that the notion of "average" that Porter and Simon use is based on a probability distribution over all possible heaps of a given size (e.g., the uniform distribution on heaps of size n), rather than across all possible sequences of insertions on a heap, since otherwise using plain insertion to build a heap would yield an amortised O(n) worst-case time too -- right?

Comment: @j_random: the proof is for single insertion in a random heap but they also investigate random insertion to a heap (which is not, after a series  of insertions, random any more, making the concept of a "random heap" a bit odd. But I don't understand what you are amortizing the algorithm over. You get worst-case behaviour inserting ordered data, and if my application tends to produce sorted sequences, insertion-based heap building will be just as n log n in the long run as in any single sequence

Comment: Read the *Building a Heap* section in the same link. "*A heap could be built by successive insertions. ... However this is not the optimal method. The optimal method starts by ... Therefore, the cost of heapifying all subtrees is: ... = O(n). This uses the fact that the given infinite series h / 2h converges to 2.*" Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap

Answer (score 6):

Consider the items `{1, 2, 3}`. There are two valid arrangements for a max-heap:

```
    3              3
  /   \          /   \
 1     2        2     1

{3, 1, 2}      {3, 2, 1}
```

Both of those satisfy the conditions necessary for a valid max-heap.

Given a full heap (i.e. all levels are full), you can swap the children of any node and still have a valid heap. Or, more generally, you can swap the children of any node as long as you maintain the shape property.

Note that "swap the children" means swapping the entire subtree anchored at that child.

In addition to swapping children, you can rearrange nodes.

Consider, for example, this max-heap:

```
      10
    /    \
   9      8
  / \    / \
 7   6  5   4
```

The order of nodes in the last level is irrelevant; any one of the leaf nodes could be a child of either 8 or 9. There are 24 possible permutations of those four children.

Other arrangements are possible, too. For example: `{10,9,6,7,8,5,4}`.

Which arrangement you get depends on the specifics of your insertion and removal algorithms, and also on the order of insertions and removals. Or, in the case of building a heap from an array (i.e. the O(n) method), the order of items in the array when you start.